# Using password from spring security to authenticate REST call

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a spring boot web app with spring security integrated with LDAP authentication. This web app internally makes REST calls. These REST calls are having username-password authentication. This username-password is the same used by spring security. Is there anyway I can get the username-password authenticated by spring security, so as to use in the REST calls. If not this way, is there any other way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a quite nice way that I think fit your case.

By default Spring Security does not store the password in memory after authentication has been made, so you need to change that. With Java config, add in `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` method:

```java
auth.eraseCredentials(false);
```

Then you can get the username and password for the *current* user with:

```java
String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
Object rawPassword  = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials();
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Security is performed based on the rule in the security properties.

This means that you just need to have spring-security enabled, the only problem is that if not authorised it will go to the Not Authorised Page which a Restful client will not understand. But if the Restful client has authenticated and been granted a valid session then it will be able to get past the Security_check and access the protected page.

I guess Spring security is working like AOP so each protected page has a Security_check crosscut that only allows access to the page if the authentication is there.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I solved the problem writing a custom AuthenticationProvider, which will perform the LDAP authentication and get the username-password for the future REST calls.